# IdentityServer4 facebook authorization without cookies

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, authorization, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 as middleware and this server will be working with facebook provider. I have read documentation about external login for google http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html I have created the same for facebook.

**Question**: Is it possible to create auth with facebook without cookies? All examples that I saw used cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IdentityServer (nor Facebook - or any other meaningful site on the WWW) will not work without cookies.